# Proving tightness of a semidefinite relaxation of a nonconvex quadratic program

Tags: matrix-rank, semidefinite-programming, non-convex-optimization, qcqp, relaxations

The Lagrangian of my semidefinite relaxation of a nonconvex QCQP (quadratically-constrained quadratic program) is
\begin{align}
L&=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\operatorname{tr}\left(\textbf{Q}_n\textbf{X}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\lambda_n\operatorname{tr}\left(\textbf{Q}_n\textbf{X}\right)-\mu\operatorname{tr}\left(\textbf{Q}_N\textbf{X}\right)-\sigma(\operatorname{tr}(\textbf{MX})-1)\\[0.35em]
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(\textbf{Q}\textbf{X}\right)-\sigma(\operatorname{tr}(\textbf{MX})-1)\\[0.35em]
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(\textbf{P}\textbf{X}\right)+\sigma
\end{align}
where $\textbf{Q}_n\nsucceq0$ (indefinite) but $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\textbf{Q}_n\succ0$ (positive definite), $\textbf{M}\succeq0$ (zero everywhere but for one positive diagonal entry, $\operatorname{rank}(\textbf{M})=1$), the primary variable is $\textbf{X}\succeq0$, the dual variables are $\lambda_n\geq0$ and $\mu,\sigma\in\mathbb{R}$.

I would like to prove that the optimal solution is rank-1, i.e. $\operatorname{rank}\textbf{X}^\star=1$.

Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) conditions of optimality:

Primal

$\bullet\;$ $\operatorname{tr}\left(\textbf{Q}_n\textbf{X}^\star\right)\geq0\;$ for $\;n=1,...,N-1$

$\bullet\;$ $\operatorname{tr}\left(\textbf{Q}_N\textbf{X}^\star\right)=0\;$

$\bullet\;$ $\operatorname{tr}\left(\textbf{M}\textbf{X}^\star\right)=1\;$

$\bullet\;$ $\textbf{X}^\star\succeq0\;$

Dual

$\bullet\;$ $\textbf{P}^\star\succeq0$

$\bullet\;$ $\lambda_n^\star\geq0\;$ for $\;n=1,...,N-1$

Complementary Slackness:

$\bullet\;$ $\operatorname{tr}(\textbf{P}^\star\textbf{X}^\star)=0$

$\bullet\;$ $\lambda_n^\star\operatorname{tr}(\textbf{Q}_n\textbf{X}^\star)=0\;$ for $\;n=1,...,N-1$

Since $\textbf{P}^\star,\textbf{X}^\star\succeq0$ follows that if $\operatorname{tr}(\textbf{P}^\star\textbf{X}^\star)=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\textbf{P}^\star\textbf{X}^\star=0$, meaning that
$$(\textbf{Q}^\star-\sigma\textbf{M})\textbf{X}^\star=\textbf{0}.$$ 
Further, since $\sigma(\operatorname{tr}(\textbf{MX})-1)$ ensures not running into the trivial solution $\textbf{X}=\textbf{0}$, there cannot be slack in that constraint and $\sigma\neq0$. Therefore, we can say that 
$$\operatorname{rank}(\textbf{Q}^\star\textbf{X}^\star)=\operatorname{rank}(\textbf{M}\textbf{X}^\star)\leq\operatorname{rank}(\textbf{M})=1.$$

At this point, I think, I would need to show that $\textbf{Q}^\star$ is full-rank. Some references considering similar problems just say it is (e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06602.pdf ) but I am not sure, why that would have to be the case. What am I missing? I'm grateful for any hints, comments or ideas.

Comment: Your text is written in very carefuly, thanks for that; but, please, don't use acronyms like QCQP, KKT, and the like (which are known by only a handful of people) without having given the full length name. Otherwise, the (surely false) impression is, by using such abbreviations, that you desire to select the happy few able to understand your domain :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment; I did not mean to exclude anybody, of course. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: (BCMBAL15CL=because comments must be at least 15 characters long) Thanks !